# ¿Porque no se centra la grilla dentro de un container en bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Estoy intentado crear una sección de artículos de un e-commerce, el problema que tengo es que estoy utilizando las grid de bootstrap, quiero que aparezcan 6 artículos por linea en Desktop pero tengo un problema y es que les tengo un margin a los artículos para que se separen un poco y se vea bien y al hacer esto no se centra respecto al contenedor. alguien sabría como poder arreglar esto?
Se que es el margin que hace que se rompa pero como podria solucionarlo y que se vea bien, tambien tengo un problema y esque lo tengo puesto que tablets se vean 3 y en moviles 2, sin embargo esto no sucede.
este es el código:

```
    <div class="row articles container mx-auto">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 article">
        <div class="article-img">
            <img src="static/img/article-test.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="article-info">
            <h3 class="article-name">Conjunto Completo</h3>
            <p class="description-article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, ea.</p>
            <div class="article-info-bottom">
                <h4 class="article-price">$2.40</h4>
                <div class="icon-container">
                    <svg class="favorite-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="m8 2.748-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                    </svg>
                <!-- <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1.314C12.438-3.248 23.534 4.735 8 15-7.534 4.736 3.562-3.248 8 1.314z"/>
                </svg> -->
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 article">
        <div class="article-img">
            <img src="static/img/article-test.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="article-info">
            <h3 class="article-name">Conjunto Completo</h3>
            <p class="description-article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, ea.</p>
            <div class="article-info-bottom">
                <h4 class="article-price">$2.40</h4>
                <div class="icon-container">
                    <svg class="favorite-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="m8 2.748-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                    </svg>
                <!-- <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1.314C12.438-3.248 23.534 4.735 8 15-7.534 4.736 3.562-3.248 8 1.314z"/>
                </svg> -->
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 article">
        <div class="article-img">
            <img src="static/img/article-test.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="article-info">
            <h3 class="article-name">Conjunto Completo</h3>
            <p class="description-article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, ea.</p>
            <div class="article-info-bottom">
                <h4 class="article-price">$2.40</h4>
                <div class="icon-container">
                    <svg class="favorite-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="m8 2.748-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                    </svg>
                <!-- <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1.314C12.438-3.248 23.534 4.735 8 15-7.534 4.736 3.562-3.248 8 1.314z"/>
                </svg> -->
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 article">
        <div class="article-img">
            <img src="static/img/article-test.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="article-info">
            <h3 class="article-name">Conjunto Completo</h3>
            <p class="description-article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, ea.</p>
            <div class="article-info-bottom">
                <h4 class="article-price">$2.40</h4>
                <div class="icon-container">
                    <svg class="favorite-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="m8 2.748-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                    </svg>
                <!-- <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1.314C12.438-3.248 23.534 4.735 8 15-7.534 4.736 3.562-3.248 8 1.314z"/>
                </svg> -->
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 article">
        <div class="article-img">
            <img src="static/img/article-test.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="article-info">
            <h3 class="article-name">Conjunto Completo</h3>
            <p class="description-article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, ea.</p>
            <div class="article-info-bottom">
                <h4 class="article-price">$2.40</h4>
                <div class="icon-container">
                    <svg class="favorite-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="m8 2.748-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                    </svg>
                <!-- <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1.314C12.438-3.248 23.534 4.735 8 15-7.534 4.736 3.562-3.248 8 1.314z"/>
                </svg> -->
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 article">
        <div class="article-img">
            <img src="static/img/article-test.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="article-info">
            <h3 class="article-name">Conjunto Completo</h3>
            <p class="description-article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, ea.</p>
            <div class="article-info-bottom">
                <h4 class="article-price">$2.40</h4>
                <div class="icon-container">
                    <svg class="favorite-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="m8 2.748-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                    </svg>
                <!-- <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1.314C12.438-3.248 23.534 4.735 8 15-7.534 4.736 3.562-3.248 8 1.314z"/>
                </svg> -->
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 article">
        <div class="article-img">
            <img src="static/img/article-test.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="article-info">
            <h3 class="article-name">Conjunto Completo</h3>
            <p class="description-article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, ea.</p>
            <div class="article-info-bottom">
                <h4 class="article-price">$2.40</h4>
                <div class="icon-container">
                    <svg class="favorite-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="m8 2.748-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                    </svg>
                <!-- <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1.314C12.438-3.248 23.534 4.735 8 15-7.534 4.736 3.562-3.248 8 1.314z"/>
                </svg> -->
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 article">
        <div class="article-img">
            <img src="static/img/article-test.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="article-info">
            <h3 class="article-name">Conjunto Completo</h3>
            <p class="description-article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, ea.</p>
            <div class="article-info-bottom">
                <h4 class="article-price">$2.40</h4>
                <div class="icon-container">
                    <svg class="favorite-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="m8 2.748-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                    </svg>
                <!-- <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1.314C12.438-3.248 23.534 4.735 8 15-7.534 4.736 3.562-3.248 8 1.314z"/>
                </svg> -->
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 article">
        <div class="article-img">
            <img src="static/img/article-test.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="article-info">
            <h3 class="article-name">Conjunto Completo</h3>
            <p class="description-article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, ea.</p>
            <div class="article-info-bottom">
                <h4 class="article-price">$2.40</h4>
                <div class="icon-container">
                    <svg class="favorite-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="m8 2.748-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                    </svg>
                <!-- <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1.314C12.438-3.248 23.534 4.735 8 15-7.534 4.736 3.562-3.248 8 1.314z"/>
                </svg> -->
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 article">
        <div class="article-img">
            <img src="static/img/article-test.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="article-info">
            <h3 class="article-name">Conjunto Completo</h3>
            <p class="description-article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, ea.</p>
            <div class="article-info-bottom">
                <h4 class="article-price">$2.40</h4>
                <div class="icon-container">
                    <svg class="favorite-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="m8 2.748-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                    </svg>
                <!-- <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1.314C12.438-3.248 23.534 4.735 8 15-7.534 4.736 3.562-3.248 8 1.314z"/>
                </svg> -->
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>

</div>

css
.article{
    margin: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Asi es como se ve, esta un poco mas a la izquierda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Necesito que quede asi centrada pero con los espacios entre si, y que sean 6 por linea

Comment: Elimina esa margin en la clase .article y revisa la clase .justify-content que te permite centrar y separar los elementos de forma automática sin necesidad de márgenes. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Comment: Si Hago eso no me lo separa, quedan pegadas; necesito el margen para que se vea bien separadas entre si

Comment: Puedes darle en [edit] a tu pregunta y muestra lo que estás intentando

Comment: ya puse imagenes para que quede mas claro lo que necesito

Answer (score 0):

Veamos, no se que imagen usas. Yo he probado con una imagen escalada para que entre en la celda (a un 95%). A cada imagen le he puesto las clases "d-block mx-auto". Y la verdad es que se ven separadas y centradas.
Le puedes añadir una clase para controlar el tamaño o un max-width, eso a tu gusto.
A parte de esto te falta un cierre de div al final y tienes etiquetas clss repetidas en los svg

```
<svg **class**="favorite-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" **class**="bi bi-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
```

No afecta al problema pero no es correcto.
En lo que yo veo funciona y es responsive. Si he interpretado bien la pregunta creo que esta solución te arregla el problemilla.
Saludos
**EDITO**
Entonces lo que necesitabas centrar es el bloque con las imágenes, que al poner el margen como no caben los 6 se redistribuyen y se descentra. ESo es flex puro. Creo que esto si te soluciona el problema.
He añadido un estilo justify-content: center al bloque articles, y he puesto margen a los div contenidos en articulos. Concretamente en la página he añadido esto

```
.articles div{
margin: 20px 10px;}
.articles{
justify-content:center;
}
```

Si quieres verla la tienes en
https://creatuweb.espaciolatino.com/ejemplos/hamburgueseria.htm
Comprueba el código fuente de la página para verel cambio, está en un style en la sección head.

Comment: no eh hecho nada de lo que me dijiste y se ve asi https://imgur.com/XpL3mxp hice lo que me dijiste y sigue sin estar centrada https://imgur.com/6bIEExz , si notas esta mas a la izquierda

Comment: Realmente entendí que el problema estaba en las imágenes, y fue lo que centré, porque el bloque lo veo centrado en mi ejemplo. La clase container lo centra, salbvo que en article tengas algo que no veo. Puedes ver como yo lo tengo y se ve centrado https://creatuweb.espaciolatino.com/ejemplos/hamburgueseria.htm. Mira el código fuente a ver si hay algo diferente con tu página, ya te digo que la clase articles no la tengo, quizás haya alguna diferencia que altera el centrado.

Comment: si, lo que pasa esque se te centra porque tienen un margin de 0 entre si https://imgur.com/dKkBxYu, pero yo necesito que tengan un margin para que se vea mejor mas estetico pero cuando les pongo el margin es que deja de estar centrado https://imgur.com/yrVY0Qv https://imgur.com/RhUJKhn mira las imagenes. Mi pregunta es como hago que aparezcan los 6 por fila, esten separadas entre si y que se mantenga centrado

Comment: Lo ultimo que recomendaste funciona hasta cierto punto... https://imgur.com/abXUsdK como ves, los de la segunda linea se centran al medio tambien cuando no llenan la fila lo cual es poco afectivo para un ecommerce que es lo que estoy haciendo. Necesito algo como esto https://imgur.com/3zO6aOD pero centrado, y que sean 6 por linea. Eh intentado todos los metodos que me recomiendan y no lo consigo